# Comparing Times in Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, compare

I have a Datagridview that has a few columns for an airline. One of the columns is "Departure" and another is "Actual Departure". Departure already has times in it, but Actual Departure does not, as the user needs to fill that in. If the time the user fills in for actual departure is before departure time, it needs to turn a certain color, if its the exact time, it will turn a certain color and if its after departure time, once again turn another color. I'm having issues with this, as I'm trying to compare the 2 columns, but I think its giving me an error because there is no value to compare in Actual Departure. Actual Departure won't have a value until run time, when the user fills it in. Maybe someone could shed some insight on whats going on or how to fix the issue.

There is multiple flights that depart, so one flight may actually leave before another so it needs to be able to skip to the next row if actual departure is still blank for that particular flight.

I was testing another way of doing this and it worked to an extent, but if the previous actual departure wasn't filled in, then that row won't change colors
[Example of old method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXwcs.png)

When I run the current code I get an error: 'String was not recognized as a valid'.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvRampBoard.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
                    DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
                    DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
                    


            if (d1 < d2)
                    {
                        //  this.dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        this.dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(247, 13, 26);
                        this.dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    }
                    else if (d1 == d2)
                    {
                        this.dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.Black;
                        this.dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 204, 0);
                        this.dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    }                      
        }
```

Comment: You should do `if(dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString())) continue;` before `DateTime d1......`

Comment: This is still giving me : String was not recognized as a valid error.

Comment: And of course, check the string format. I would prefer to use datetime.TryParse and if false do something else or continue

Comment: You commented that… _”There is multiple flights that depart, so one flight may actually leave before another so it needs to be able to skip to the next row if actual departure is still blank for that particular flight.”_ … and before this you state that… _”I'm having issues with this, as I'm trying to compare the 2 columns, but I think its giving me an error because there is no value to compare in Actual Departure.”_ … you are correct in both statements, however the posted code does none of this “checking” for any of the grid cell values being `null` or empty.

Comment: As already suggested, the `DateTime.TryParse` will help in figuring out if the cell value is `null` or the `string` date time value is in an invalid format.

Comment: is it windows application or web application ?

Comment: Which line in the code throws the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Use `TimeSpan`. Convert the `time` to `TimeSpan` and compare it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvRampBoard.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    TimeSpan t1 = TimeSpan.Parse(dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
    TimeSpan t2 = TimeSpan.Parse(dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());



    if (TimeSpan.Compare(t1, t2) == -1)
    {
       this.dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
       this.dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(247, 13, 26);
       this.dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
    else if (TimeSpan.Compare(t1, t2) == 0)
    {
       this.dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.Black;
       this.dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
    else
    {
       this.dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 204, 0);
       this.dgvRampBoard.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```